# DDD Multi tenant design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm designing a generic multi-tenant identity system (Authentication / Authorization), but I have some doubt if I'm designing it the correct way.

Currently, the design is this:

AR **User** with reference to **Tenant** and a specific **organizational unit** where the user belongs to.
AR **Tenant** has a list of entity **Organisational unit**

The **Organisational unit** in this context is a tree structure describing the organization, for example Aphabet -> Google -> Development

My question is

Should the **organizational unit** be a root entity as it is referenced by a **user** or is this allowed?

I have modelled it as an entity of **Tenant** because the **organizational unit** cannot exist without a **Tenant**, so in my mind, the **organizational unit** should not be an AR.

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your question it's not clear to me what your application should look like and what's the purpose of it. What are you modeling? Can you provider more detailed information?

From what I can understand your entities are: **Tenant**, **OrganizationalUnit** and **User**.

What are the relationships between **Tenant** and **OrganizationalUnit**? It seems that a **Tenant** should contain many **OrganizationalUnit**s but what is the purpose of **OrganizationalUnit**? Is it to group and organize **Users** (for example when working in specific teams or being part of specific parts of a company (dev, sales, design etc.)?

The first thing that people come across when they start with DDD are **Aggregates**. They are the most misunderstood concept and are difficult to understand. I think that when a person starts modeling applications he/she should not start with trying to define **Aggregates**. Start with defining the entities and clarifying the relationships between them. After you do that, analize your application and the technical issues that it will have and think of how you can organize your entities into **Aggregates** to solve these problems.

Have you read the [DDD book by Eric Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)? If you haven't I strongly recommend it.

As a pattern **Aggregates** are used to solve couple of problems (it's not a complete list):

- Define transactional boundaries of changes to your entities. What entities should change together as a whole and what entities can change independently of one another? Most applications today are multi-user, so you may have concurrent operations (like adding multiple **Users** at the same time to **OrganizationalUnit** from different **Admins**)
- Limit the number of references one entity has to other entities so when you load them from the database you don't load one entity with a collection that contains 1 000 0000 other entities that may cause your server to ran out of memory and crash. That is not very practical and wont work.
- Clarify traversal directions. Bidirectional associations are hard to maintain.  For example you may have a **User** that belongs to an **Organizational Unit** and an **OgranizationalUnit** contains many **Users** so you have many to many relationship. Loading one **User** with all **OrganizationalUnits** and loading all other **Users** that belong to those **OrganizationalUnits** just to change the name of that **User** isn't very practical.

That's where **Repositories** can help. If you want to get **OrganizationalUnits** for a specific **User** you will have **OrganizationUnitRepository** with **getOrganizationalUnitsForUser(userID)** method. If you want to find **Users** for **OrganizationalUnit** you will have **UserRepository** with **getUsersForOrganizationalUnit(unitID)** method. This way you will use **Repositories** to traverse relationships between entities organized into aggregates.

Start with defining the entities first with their relationships, analyze the issues of you app and then organize them in Aggregates based on the problems that you have (refactor later if you don't get it right).

In your case you can:

- Have all entities be part of separate aggregates and have each entity be the root of it's aggregate. Have repositories for all of them. In your **Services** you will use **Repositories** to retrieve multiple entities if you need them for the specific operation.
- If you don't think that a **Tenant** will have thousands of **OgranizationalUnits** you can have it part of the **Tenant** Aggregate and load them together. In this case since **OgranizationalUnits** are hierarchical you will have to load parent and children together. If you don't want that use  **ReferenceByID** and have a property with parentID only for each **OgranizationalUnit** instead of loading a collection of children and parent.

One problem with distributing entities to different aggregates is consistency boundary. This way you have to introduce eventual consistency between different aggregates and it's harder to enforce some rules.

For example lets say that you have a limit of how many **Users** can be part of a **Tenant**. If **Tenant** entity and **OrganizationalUnit** entity are part of the same aggregate then they are in the same consistency boundary. This way you will load the aggregate, make the check and if it's violated raise an error, if not add the **User** and save the aggregate. In the case of multi-user scenario, if two **Admins** load the same aggregate and each one adds a **User** to **OrganizationalUnit**, during the save you can use [Optimistic Concurrency](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) to resolve conflicts so that you don't end up with **Users** count that exceeds the limit.

If you break down the aggregate in two, then they are in different consistency boundaries and enforcing this rule becomes harder. This is called **Set Based Validation**. You can search for information on this subject it but it's difficult to find any, so I cant point to anywhere.. sorry about that.

If you have such issues with set validation, and you can go with clustering entities without having performance issues with loading them, then do it and don't do **Set Based Validation**

For more details you can check [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/). It discusses these problems and solutions in details. It actually has a **Tenant** part of it's model too :)

Comment: Its a generic identity application for internal use.

The entities are indeed tenant, organizational unit and user.

The organizational units are indeed specific parts of the company like finance, sales, marketing, but can also be used for example companies and sub companies like alphabet -> google -> marketing